# Can responsibilities of bootstrap classloader and extension classloader be combined?

Tags: java, performance, classloader

I want to know whether responsibilities of above mentioned classloaders in java can be combined? (Not by the user/programmer but by JVM developers)
Bootstrap loader loads classes from jdk/jre/lib/* and extension loader loads from jdk/jre/lib/ext/* , so what wrong in combining them?

And by doing this **one level of delegation can be saved too**. Isn't it?

The only difference that I know between them is that bootstrap classloader has been implemented in native language whereas extension classloader has been implemented in java itself

And if It is necessary to keep them bifurcated then please tell the reason bethind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is no technical reason that the JVM could not load lib/ext classes from the bootstrap class loader.  There might be some minor security implications (classes loaded by the bootstrap class loader are given extra privileges) and backwards compatibility implications (some advanced applications assume the extra class loader exists), but given that you need to modify the JRE install, I think these concerns are somewhat minor.

The Modular Run-Time Images ([JEP 220](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220)) feature of Java 9 proposes to remove the extension mechanism, but they propose to keep the extension class loader in the hierarchy for backward compatibility.  It remains to be seen whether removing the extension mechanism will cause too many problems for real world applications or whether the extension class loader will remain or be removed in subsequent releases.

Comment: Thanks. I was unaware of JEP 220. Great Information.